# Window Binding to UserControl ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need help with binding a window to a user control view model. Here's my user control, nice and simple.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowBindTest.UserControlTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WindowBindTest.UserControlViewModel"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
<ViewModel:UserControlViewModel></ViewModel:UserControlViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>            
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's my view model

```
namespace WindowBindTest
{
    public class UserControlViewModel
    {
        public Window hostWindow { get; set; }|
        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            // I want to set the host window
            // If something isn't defined then close the host window.
        }    

    }
}
```

I could use a button to close the window but what if I didn't want to use a button. Is there a way to do that? 
Could I pass in the parent window into the constructor?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Can you be more specific, do you need to know how to do DataBinding with MVVM pattern in WPF?

Comment: @Pat: do you have any idea, how you want to close window without button. You can bind window closing with some event.

Comment: I don't really care how to close it without a button. I just want the hostwindow to reference whatever the parent window is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but on the Parent window, you can give the window a x:Name. Then, you can pass it into the Child window using ElementName binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MVVM but you will need to use a service. In fact, this is where MVVM is weak (without using a framework such as Prism et al.). The following is a link to [disore's DialogService class on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern). it is awesome, but it will take time to get to grips with how it works.

The above library will enable you to close a View from a ViewModel.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I like how they use System.Diagnostics.Contracts; they are making sure that Person exists before loading the model view. I could do it that way. I kind of make sure it exist after I loaded my view.

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept this and some of your other answers if they help you. All the best and good luck...